# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp' was corrupted

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

When i am running this code I am getting below error as

`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp' was corrupted`

```
int main()
{
    UINT8 temp[7];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = 0x01;
    }
    return 0;
}//The error falls here
```

Please help me.

Comment: Your loop termination condition is `i <= 7` rather than `i < 7`.  Which means it will try to write to `temp[7]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @All:- I am really sorry for this silly mistake..

Comment: Note you can just initialize the array, and avoid `for` altogther: `UINT temp[7] = { 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are accessing array out of boundry

change:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

Or more C++ way:

```
std::fill_n(temp, 7, 0x01);
```

Comment: +1 for proposing a C++ algorithm, but I'd prefer `std::fill` instead of `std::fill_n`, since the OP is writing the _whole_ array, not a subset of it. Moreover, I'd use `_countof()` instead of embedding a "magic number" like `7`.

Answer (score 2):

the size of `temp` is `7` and the for loop reach `8` elements and not `7`

change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
```

by

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

The array index in c start from 0. so if you go from index 0 to  index 7 in your array that means you reach the `8th` element in your array, but your array size is 7

Answer (score 2):

The cycle should be excluding 7 - your array is of size 7, so there is no element with index 7 in it.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring UINT8 temp[7]; creates an array of 7 variables. Starting from temp[0] to temp[6]

Your for loop however tries to access temp[7] which is undefined.
The below loop will work

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    temp[i] = 0x01;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 7 elements in the array ([0..6]), your for loop tries to access 8 elements [0..7], therefore you get a corrupted stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    temp[i] = 0x01;
}
```

This will help you.. you are writing back to the temp again.. that is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Note that in C and C++, **array indexes are 0-based**. So, if you have an array of *N* items, valid index values are 0,1,2,...,(*N*-1).

In your case, *N* = 7, so valid index values are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.

So, substitute `<=` with `<` in your for loop:

```
UINT8 temp[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)  // Use <, not <=
 ....
```

Moreover, there is a convenient [`_countof()` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) available with VS in `<stdlib.h>`, which makes your code easier to *read* and *maintain* (instead of using the "magic number" 7 in your `for` loop):

```
for (int i = 0; i < _countof(temp); i++)
```

Using `_countof()`, if you change the size of the array, your loop code will still work, without modifying 7 to the new array size.

Note also that in C++11 it's possible to use *range-based for loops* (but they are not available in VC10/Visual Studio 2010, which you used as a tag in this question).

Note that if you want to fill a buffer with a given byte sequence you can use `memset` (a C-like way):

```
memset(temp, 0x01, sizeof(temp));
```

Or, more generally (even for elements larger than one byte), you can use C++ `std::fill` from `<algorithm>`:

```
fill(begin(temp), end(temp), 0x01);
```

Using an explicit algorithm like `std::fill` makes your code more readable, because it rises the "semantic level" of the source code (you just read "*fill*" instead of reading a "raw" `for` loop, the meaning of which you have to interpret).